# local drive audio use to codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, audio

I use **codeigniter** and stored a lot of audio files on my local drive.

**C:\XtendLogger\Waves\20171129** is my audio file path to the audio files i want to use. Therefore I tried the following code, but it doesn't work:

```
<audio src="C:\XtendLogger\Waves\20171129\Karuthavanlaam Galeejaam.mp3'" preload="auto" type="audio/mpeg" controls></audio>
```

**I don't want store this audio file in my codeigniter assets folder**.

Comment: http://fhoerni.free.fr/comp/web_server_php.png - you need those files on your webserver ;)

Comment: Do you get any errors or what?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply play them using the audio class of javascript as bwlow:

```
var audio = new Audio('C:\XtendLogger\Waves\file_name');
audio.play();
```